# mingw make is displaying version and exiting

Tags: windows, makefile

i'm trying to make fltk 1.3.x r9678 after using cmake to generate mingw makefiles. upon running make, windows version and copyright info are displayed instead of compiling fltk. i'm using the latest version of mingw

Comment: Sounds like you're running the wrong make. Check your PATH for others

Answer (score 0):

I just went through building FLTK 1.3.2 using MinGW and there was no need to create your own makefiles. Here are my notes with some comments in parenthesis:

1. Start Menu - All Programs - MinGW folder - MinGW shell (start MinGW
   shell)
2. cd to fltk-1.3.2 (in the MinGW shell change directory to the root
   folder of FLTK)
3. make clean (clean out previous bad build if any)
4. LDFLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" ./configure
   --enable-threads --enable-localjpeg --enable-localpng --enable-localzlib (configure it to build for MinGW)
5. make
6. make install

Hope this helps others in the future.